# How do I structure a generic item that can have a relationship with different tables?

Tags: sql, activerecord, database-design, foreign-keys, relationship

In my example, I have a `watch`, which is an indication a user wants notifications about events on a different item, say a `group` and an `organization`.

I see two ways to do this:

1. Have a `groupwatch` resource, with a `groupwatch` table, with `id`,`user`,`group` (group FK to `group` resource and table); and a `orgwatch` resource, with a `orgwatch` table, with `id`,`user`,`organization` (org FK to `organization` resource and table)
2. Have a generic `watch` resource, with a `watch` table, with `id`,`user`,`type`,`typeid`. `type` is one of `group` or `organization`, and `typeid` is the ID of the `group` or `organization` being watched.

Since both of them are watches, it seems a waste to have two different tables and resources to watch 2 different objects. It gets worse if I start watching 4, 5, 6, 20, 50 different types of resources.

On the other hand, a foreign key relationship appears impossible if I just have a generic `typeid`, which means that my database (if relational) and my framework (activerecord or anything else) cannot enforce it correctly.

How do I best implement this type of "association to different types of record/table for each record in my table"?

UPDATE:

Are my only choices for doing this:

- separate tables/resources for each `watch` type, which enables the database to enforce relational integrity and do joins
- single table for all `watches`, but I will have to enforce relational integrity and do joins at the app level?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a new type of resource once every six months, you may want to define your tables in such a way that adding new resources involves changing data definitions.  If you add a new resource type every week, you may want to make your data definitions stay the same when you add new types.  There's a downside to either choice.

If you do choose to define table in such a way that the types are visible in the table structure, there are two patterns often used with type/subtype (aka class/subclass) situations.

One pattern has been called "single table inheritance".  Put data about all the types in a single table, and leave some columns NULL wherever they do not apply.

Another pattern has been called "class table inheritance".  Define one table for the superclass, with all the data that is common to all the types. Then define tables for each subtype (subclass) to contain class specific data.  Make the primary key of the subtype tables a duplicate of the primary key in the supertype table, and also declare it as a foreign key that references the primary key of the supertype table.  It's going to be up to the app, at insert time, to replicate the value of the primary key in the supertype table over in the subtype table.

I like Fowlers' treatment of these two patterns.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html
http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html

This matter of sharing primary keys has a few beneficial effects.

First, it enforces the one-to-one nature of the ISa relationships.
Second, it makes it easy to find out whether a given entry belongs to a desired subtype, by just joining with the subtype table.  You don't really need an extra type field.
Third, it speeds up the joins, because of the index that gets built when you declare a primary key.

If you want a structure that can adapt to new attributes without changing data definitions, you can look into E-A-V design.  Be careful, though.  Sometimes this results in data that is nearly impossible to use, because the logical structure is so obscure.  I usually think of E-A-V as an anti-pattern for this reason, although there are some who really like the results they get from it.

Comment: this is great, thank you. I didn't even think of it as an EAV pattern. In some ways it is, but I am not taking it all the way through, just to deal with the `watch` resource. To be fair, whenever I add something that might be watched, it definitely will be in its own table; the main reason I am looking at the pattern is because a "watch" is just a "watch", and it would make sense to grab it from one place. I will read Martin's stuff right now. Upvote!

Comment: Follow up: This is definitely a "new type of resource every six months" structure. If tomorrow we add a `team` resource, I don't mind changing the data definition, adding a `team` table. The question is, do I also need a `teamwatch` table, when the only difference between `teamwatch` and `groupwatch` is the FK relationship `group`<->`group` vs `team`<->`team`?

Comment: That will depend on the specifics of your case.

Comment: So is my choice basically between: a- separate tables/resources for each watch type but with database+framework enforced relational integrity; b- single table for all watches, but I will have to enforce relational integrity at the app level?

Comment: Your last comment confuses me.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will update the question to clarify.

Comment: In the meantime, I reworded my answer to clarity a couple of points about sharing primary keys.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So you are seeing those are my choices. Is there any way to use a sort-of-EAV in a limited case (like the watches) while still allowing primary and foreign keys (and therefore fast joins, referential integrity, etc.)?

Comment: Hopefully somebody else can chime in with how to use EAV productively.  Off the top of my head, I'll guess that, yes, it's possible to design a schema where part of it is EAV while the rest of it is standard relational.  But I haven't done it.